# Reading File System Events from Linux Kernel without Inotify

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, inotify, fsevents

In Linux to read File System Events, most of us use Inotify which is really a Good One. But it has it's limitations.
I have to keep track of all the directories i have to watch and get a inotify descriptor for each and every directory. Let's say i want to monitor my Whole System and it has about 10 million directories. Listing and queuing them for inotify API itself would take hours. It would eat a lot of memory also.
And i certainly can't watch directories more than that specified in max_user_watches in /etc/syscntl.conf or /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches .

But we know that each and every file system event is monitored by Kernel and we use inotify API to register for a certain directory modifications. But how do i read fs events directly from kernel without API ..? [ In Mac OS X, i can read from /dev/fsevents , likewise if i can read from /proc or something like that, it would be great]. I'm ready to write a Kernel Module too, but please share some light on this.

Comment: This is a very useful question. I have also been trying  to implement something similar on a Linux distribution, but didn't succeed. Maybe `lsof` will already fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the *virus scanner* stuff? Ie, [Fanotify](http://lwn.net/Articles/339399/), also *fsnotify* and hooked to *dnotify* and *inotify*.  This depends on [kernel version](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_36); present in some form since approximately 2.6.36 (early 2011).

Some kernel files,

- [proc documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)
- [fsnotify.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/fsnotify.h)
- [fsnotify_backend.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/fsnotify_backend.h)
- [fanotify.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/fanotify.h)

Lwn.net links,

- [API overview](http://lwn.net/Articles/339399/)
- [Main Commit notice](http://lwn.net/Articles/339253/)
- [Various commits](http://lwn.net/Articles/306804/)